# Understanding change of coordinates function

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

On page 69, “[Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html)”, says:

> 8.1. Coordinate vector. Let $V$ be a vector space with a basis $B:=\left\{b_{1},\ldots ,b_{n}\right\}$. Any vector $v \in V$ admits a unique representation as a linear combination
>   $$v=x_{1}b_{1}+\ldots +x_{n}b_{n}=\sum ^{n}_{k=1}x_{k}b_{k}$$
>
> The numbers $x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}$ are called the coordinates of the vector $v$ in the basis B. It is convenient to join these coordinates into the so-called coordinate vector of v relative to the basis B, which is the column vector
>   $$[v]_B:=\begin{pmatrix}
> x_{1} \\
> \vdots  \\
> x_{n}
> \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}$$
>   Note that the mapping
>   $$v\to[v]_B$$
>   is an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$. It transforms the basis
>   $b_{1},\ldots ,b_{n}$ to the standard basis
>   $e_{1},\ldots ,e_{n}$.

I do not understand the last paragraph. I thought the output of the coordinate function gave the coordinates with respect to basis $B$. Those are precisely the coefficients that multiply each of basis $B$ vectors. Can someone throw some light?

Comment: For instance, the coefficients of $b_1$ in basis $B$ are $(1,0,0,\dots,0)$, that is $b_1=1\cdot b_1+0\cdot b_2+\dots+0\cdot b_n$. So the coefficients of $b_1$ form the vector $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ in the standard basis. Likewise the coefficients of $b_i$ form $e_i$ for all $i$. I'm not sure what you don't understand, nor what you mean by *"Those are precisely the coefficients that multiply each of basis $B$ vectors."*

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I would expect that, the coefficients in the linear combination $$v=x_{1}b_{1}+\ldots +x_{n}b_{n}=\sum ^{n}_{k=1}x_{k}b_{k},$$ to be the same in the output column vector that belong to $\mathbb{F}^n$. If I understand correctly, they are the coefficients _with respect to basis B_, not to the standard basis.

Comment: But the basis $B$ is a basis of $V$, and is unrelated to $\Bbb F^n$. Keep in mind that the mapping $v\to[v]_B$ maps from $V$ to $\Bbb F^n$. What the author says is the image of $b_i$ (in $V$) is $e_i$ (in $\Bbb F^n$). My previous comment what probably not clear enough about that, I should have stated "in the standard basis **of** $\Bbb F^n$".

Comment: Thank you. Starting to understand. Can I ask you for an example?